# Parcel dosen't work with simple html and Ts file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, semantic-versioning

I have just installed parcel using the command

> npm install -g parcel-bundler

and all worked fine.
After than I've created a simple html file:

```
<html>
  <body>
  <script src="./src/index.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

A simple Typescript file to test:

```
console.log('hi there!');
```

But it gave me this error after running parcel `index.html`

```
Build Error
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Mine\React Typescript\TypeScript Learning\mapsProject\src\index.ts: Invalid Version: undefined

    at new SemVer (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\node_modules\semver\semver.js:314:11)
    at compare (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\node_modules\semver\semver.js:647:10)
    at lt (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\node_modules\semver\semver.js:688:10)
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:276:22
    at Object.default (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:22:12)
    at getEnvPlugins (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\transforms\babel\env.js:62:34)
    at getEnvConfig (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\transforms\babel\env.js:12:25)
    at async getBabelConfig (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\transforms\babel\config.js:32:19)
    at async babelTransform (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\transforms\babel\transform.js:6:16)
    at async JSAsset.pretransform (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\assets\JSAsset.js:83:5)
Please help me out, this is my package.json
```

My dependencies:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "semver": "^7.3.4"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me with the described error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually a well-known problem in Parcel's newest version. I would suggest you to move up your Parcel to version 2, as it is newer and much more stable.

If you still insist to use the version 1 of Parcel, you might need to revert to version `1.12.3`.

```sh
npm uninstall parcel-bundler
npm i -g parcel-bundler@1.12.3
```

Further reading: [A well known issue in Parcel's repository, exactly like your problem](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/5943).

Comment: got exactly the very same error when using 1.12.3